# Account activation in Nuxt

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

How do I make a Nuxt page perform a POST to a particular URL in order to activate the account based on the parameters in the URL of the page?

So, for example, if the user clicks on a link in an email like this:-

https://example.com/activate/MQ/abcdef/

I would like the page to send the "MQ" and the "abcdef" as data to /users/activation/ and redirect the user to the login page of the site if the response is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page named callback

//callback.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <loading />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import loading from '~/components/common/loading';
export default {
  components: {
    loading
  },
  mounted() {
    this.login();
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      let data = {        
        YOUR_PARAMS
      };
       this.$axios
        .$post(`YOUR_URL`, data)
        .then(res => {
          if (YOUR_CONDITIONS) {
            this.$router.push({ path: '/LINK_A' });
         else
             this.$router.push({ path: '/LINK_B' });
      
          }
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```